# how to defined and object collections in Jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

How would you do this? Let's say you have a FrontPage object that is a collection of Many Post object. But it is not any kind of collection. It is a collection made of known members: 5 latest news (LatestNews#1, LatestNews#2, ... LatestNews#5) 5 popular news, and more, up to 25 individual Post Objects.

You can have a FrontPageObject like this....

```
entity FrontPageConfig {
creationDate Instant required
latestNews1 Long
latestNews2 Long
latestNews3 Long
latestNews4 Long
latestNews5 Long
topNews1 Long
and so on....}

entity Post {
body TextBlob minbytes(3) maxbytes(50000) required
}
```

... where the Long attribute represents the id of the Post object.

But when you do it, you have to load the object in Angular and make 25 calls to the the server to call the Posts.

How can I have an FrontPageConfig object that has all the properties as defined (latestNews1) Post objects inside and that I only have to call once.

Thanks again.

PD: I tried with OneToOne relationships:

FrontPageConfig{topNews1(id)} to Post{topNews1(id)}

And OneToMany or ManyToOne:

FrontPageConfig{topNews1(id)} to Post{topNews1(id)}

But it is not a defined collection!

And this relationship OneToMany {

Post{topNews1} to FrontPageConfig{topNews1}

Does not give the object, only the id!

Comment: I would suggest creating an endpoint yourself that makes required queries in the back-end corresponding service. That way, you would only need to call that endpoint to get all the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for [Data Transfer Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (DTOs).

- Create a custom API endpoint and in that method, query the database.
- Create a custom DTO object (such as FrontPageDTO) with the fields you want to return to the user interface.
- In your service class (or resource if you don't use services), make the queries through the repository to get the information you need.

  - Query for 5 latest news and 5 top news, then map that data to the DTO fields
- Return the DTO once the fields are set

Comment: Thanks again Jon. I imagine, that at the same time, you are saying that it can not be achieved automatically by the JDL generator with some kind of flag, right? Would it be someting interesting to improve, right? I think it is a quite common use case, isn't it?

Comment: it might be possible to add DTO generation to JDL but most of this depends heavily on your custom business logic which is hard to write templates for.  JHipster projects will always require some customization to fit your needs

Comment: Thanks Jon, I guess this ( https://www.jhipster.tech/using-dtos/ ) is the way a Post should be called from the FrontPageConfig entity that has the Ids, right? using MapStruct (just in case anyone has the same problem)

Comment: The simplest solution is to use the DTO class’s get/set methods.  You could probably configure a mapstruct mapper but I’m not sure exactly how in this case.